# Which version of SQL Server client does BIDS come free?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, bids

I am struggling to find the *right version of the software to download to get BIDS for free with SQL Server client.*

**I tried installing SQL server 2008 R2 edition . I was able to see BIDS . But, when i launch it , ia m getting error as follows:**

```
To design Integration Services Packages in Business Intelligence Development Studio, Integration
Services has to be installed by one of these editions of SQL Server 2008 R2: Standard,Enterprise,
Developer, or Evaluation. To install Integration Services, run SQL Server Setup and select 
integration services
```

Please help

Comment: The error message tells you which versions include it.  Which version are you currently trying to use?

Comment: SQL Server 2008R2 Express edition

Comment: See the link, below. May be it will turn useful.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993%28v=sql.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no free version of BIDS.

You need either SQL Server 2008 Standard, Developer, or Enterprise edition to get access to BIDS. You can get it via Amazon for example.

**Edit**:

You can see the different versions and their features via this link, as Jithin has pointed out in the comments: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993%28v=sql.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

So in essence you are running a version of SQL Server that supports BIDS, you simply need to setup integration services in order for it to work on the installation machine.